# Responsive svg and the image behind it should coincide

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a code that I want to make responsive. It has an image as a background with svg triangles above it that coincide with the image center. But it's not responsive. Trying to make it responsive , the image gets smaller but the svgs remain the same.

the triangles are svgs and the rest is the background
[image]

```css
#wheelOfLife {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    float: center;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin: auto;
    background: url("https://www.coachinguniverset.dk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/123.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    float: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.triangle svg {
    /* Default height */
    height: 200px;
    fill-opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="wheelOfLife">
        
        <div id="career" class="triangle">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 110.5 155.5">
           <path d="M0 45.5L110.5 0v155.5L0 45.5z"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="personalGrowth" class="triangle">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 110.5 155.5">
          <path d="M0 45.5L110.5 0v155.5L0 45.5z"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="finance" class="triangle">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 110.5 155.5">
          <path d="M0 45.5L110.5 0v155.5L0 45.5z"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="health" class="triangle">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 110.5 155.5">
          <path d="M0 45.5L110.5 0v155.5L0 45.5z"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="family" class="triangle">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 110.5 155.5">
          <path d="M0 45.5L110.5 0v155.5L0 45.5z"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="relationships" class="triangle">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 110.5 155.5">
          <path d="M0 45.5L110.5 0v155.5L0 45.5z"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="socialLife" class="triangle">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 110.5 155.5">
          <path d="M0 45.5L110.5 0v155.5L0 45.5z"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
        <div id="attitude" class="triangle">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 110.5 155.5">
          <path d="M0 45.5L110.5 0v155.5L0 45.5z"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

svg doesn't scale in the same way that raster images do. You may want to check out this article from CSS-Tricks
https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

It seems like it would really simplify things if you choose either raster or svg instead of both. You could bring the background image into inkscape and recreate it, then affect the whole svg with the same controls.